# how to Call Fragment from main class (appCompatActivity)

Tags: android

I have the main class and more 3 fragment classes, when I call a fragment from a main it do not works. How could I call a  Fragment in main class which is extended from appCompacAtivity? i had tried many things but still facing the same problem please help me out... Here is my code below...thank you in advance

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;

ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new HomeFragment(),"Welcome");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new DealsFragment(), "Deals");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new MakemydateFragment(), "Make My Day");
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    FragmentManager fr = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fr.beginTransaction();
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_deals) {

       // Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DealsFragment.class); // here i want to call fragment class
       // startActivity(intent);
       // ft.replace(R.id.container, DealsFragment.class);
       // ft.commit();


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_knowledgezone) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_makemyday) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_specials){

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_account) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}



}

public class DealsFragment extends Fragment {

private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;


public DealsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_deals, container, false);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager2);


    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), ImageOneDeals.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), ImageTwoDeals.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), ImageThreeDeals.class.getName()));

    mPagerAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), fragments);

    pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    return view;
}

}
```

Comment: what do u mean by calling the fragment?

Comment: u have to commit the transaction like ft.commit()

Comment: @varunkr i want to call DealsFragment in class MainActivity

Comment: @AdeelTurk i am have problem with this line ft.replace(R.id.container_fragment, DealsFragment.class);

Comment: ft.replace(android.R.id.container, DealsFragment.class); this is the problem because you are passing DealsFragment.class intaed of passing the instance of the fragment

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html   see the replace function parameters

Comment: ok !!..so how can i pass the object of the fragment can you please help me out with that code...

Comment: `ft.replace(android.R.id.container, DealsFragment.newInstance(params));` if that's how you generate your fragments. Also, is the R.id.container the generated android layout? If this is so, then you can't replace statically added fragments dynamically.

Comment: @Nick you can not resolve the method newInstance(params));

Comment: My apologies. Call your `Fragment.instantiate(....)` or however you are managing new fragments method in there instead. Or make the instance of the fragment and pass it into the replace(viewId, Fragment) function. Fragment transactions require the actual instance of your fragment. They don't work like intents where you pass it in using Activity.class

Comment: @Nick i made the instance of fragment and passed in replace...but it show s error in replace where we write instance..replace(viewId, Fragment(Here it shows error) )

Comment: Did you check your Fragment imports? There are two different ones. The replace() method requires android.app.Fragment. Make sure you haven't imported android.support.v4.Fragment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call any method of the `fragment` from the Activity then do this.

Create object of the `fragment` class and then call the method.

```
   RegFragment fragment = (RegFragment) adapter.getFragment(1);
        fragment.onRegError(response);
```